# Share Power BI Queries between Reports using PowerBI Desktop Client

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I use a Sharepoint Online Site collection to do Portfolio Management and I have different subsites for each project that include lists for Goals, tasks, issues, change requests, etc... All subsites use the same template.

I'm currently using Power BI to do data aggregation for all the tasks, issues, etc... of every project subsites.

I'm using Power BI desktop client for all the reports.

Since I'm doing different Reports for issues, risks, tasks, etc... I would like to create a Report and then a Dashboard to consolidate all the Portfolio of projects and build some KPIs. And for that, instead of having to create all the different queries for the project issues, tasks, etc... all over again , I would like to use the queries that I've already build before.

If I'm not mistaken, I'm not able to share my queries in Power BI Desktop Client neither in Power BI in O365 or using Data Azure Catalog! Right?

Can someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sharing"? You can copy and paste queries (with all transformation steps) between reports in the query edit mode - is it what you're after?

Comment: Share = reuze in other Power BI reports without having to copy paste all the queries and the subsequent transformation steps.

Comment: You can copy the entire query object, as opposite to query text. It will copy transformation steps too. http://imgur.com/a/43cT4

Comment: Also might be worth setting up a template with common queries and relationships and then branching off from it.

Comment: Also, you can right click on a query in query editor, select advanced editor, and it will display the entire Power Query script for it. You could inspect it and potentially generate elsewhere in a more automated manner, for example if you have big number of tables and columns with similar transformation sequences. You can then paste the script in a new blank query.

Comment: All viable solutions! Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome :)